# DevExpress report Main and Detail reports stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, devexpress, xtrareport

I have to create an XtraReport with two sections; master and detail. For example, categories - is master and their products is detail:

Category1

- Prod1
- Prod2
- Prod3

Category2

- Prod4
- Prod5
- Prod6

The problem is that both categories and relevant products come from Stored Procedures. So I have 2 stored procedures, the first master stored procedure is without parameters, the second detail store procedure has the parameter of CategoryId (that comes from first Stored Procedure).

I can't find a way to set the CategoryId parameter value of the second stored procedure from the first stored procedure.

In the stored procedure designer I can see this, but I can't set the parameter value to first store procedure ID.

[image]

Comment: When I did something similar years ago I loaded the "detail" collection using code inside the "ParentChanged"(Don't remember the exact name) event of the report.

Comment: Thanks for info, can you please copy and paste the method as answer? It will help me.

Comment: I think you need the DataSourceRowChanged event. Your "detail" report can be bound to a collection that is populated inside that event.Use e.CurrentRow to get data about the "current" master row,

Comment: Ok, I will look at it. Some code of accessing parent and setting list to its detailed rows would be great, maybe your old code would help :)

Comment: I don't have it,if I have time I'll install the components on a vm and try it

Comment: ok, don't lose your time then :) I will try your approach and let you know. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @GeorgeVovos  Hello, I've found solution and posted below after a while. Maybe it is interesting to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using **xsSubreport** component, create separate sub-report and attach to it.

You can pass parameters to it from outer(main) report, and  it will fetch data in it based on outer parameters

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKRsXxjr_EI

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm being a little late on this, but I'm sure that the DevExpress built-in data access solution (the **EFDataSource** component) does not support this kind of integration as the entire source is filled at once. As I understand, you need to create a [Master-Detail Report](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4785/Creating-Reports-in-Visual-Studio/Getting-Started-with-DevExpress-Reporting/Creating-Popular-Reports/Creating-a-Master-Detail-Report-using-Detail-Report-Bands). In this case, the best option here will be to define control bindings in [Object Binding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/17784/Creating-Reports-in-Visual-Studio/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Providing-Data-to-Reports/Tutorials-and-Code-Examples/Bind-a-Report-to-an-Object-Data-Source) mode, and then, at runtime, execute both stored procedures manually using your DBContext class. Assign the first result set directly to **XtraReport.DataSource**. The second stored procedure should be executed at runtime several times in the **DetailReportBand.BeforePrint** event handler. You can get the master row's CategoryId as `rootReport.GetCurrentColumnValue("CategoryID")`

I hope this helps. If my explanation is not clear, I'm sure the DevExpress support team will be happy to explain more and provide you with an example (not sure why you've not done that in the first place though — StackOverflow is not meant for discussing vendor-specific products)